# Finding the Mid-Point of the side of a square.

Tags: geometry

Given a square drawn on a piece of paper, is it possible to find the midpoint of one of its sides using the following tools:
-A pencil (used ONLY to draw lines)
-An infinitely long and infinitesimally thin unmarked straight edge

Comment: Can I use any other tricks, like marking the straight edge or folding the paper?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible.

[image]

Select a point $P$ outside the square and draw lines through $P$ and the corners $A$ and $B$. These lines intersect $DC$ at the points $E$ and $F$. Now draw the lines $AF$ and $BE$. These lines intersect at $G$. A line through $P$ and $G$ will now intersect $AB$ at its midpoint $M$.

We know $M$ is the midpoint by the following argument:

Using the [Intercept Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercept_theorem) we know that $$ \frac{HF}{MB} = \frac{EH}{AM}$$
But from similar triangles we also know that $$ \frac{EH}{MB} = \frac{HF}{AM}$$
Combining these two equations we find that $$ \left( \frac {AM}{MB}\right)^2 = 1$$
which means $AM = MB$.